# iPhone blueprint/sketching/drawing software

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Does anyone in the SO community know of any software that will let you drag different iOS components around on an iPhone (or even iPad) to help make models or blue prints of app designs? It is only for visual purposes. It doesn't deal with code or anything like that. It's just for positioning and planning the way an app will look. Has anyone seen or used any software like this?

Comment: you could ask google for mockups and iphone.

Comment: you can use the simulator for this reasonably well.

Comment: Look on the bright side, if you get no answers posted, then you may have a good idea for a new app!

Comment: simulator will NOT work well because I specifically said I don't want to write code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Blueprint](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blueprint/id405203705?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4) is an app designed for that purpose. I've never used it personally, but I know some folks who think it's pretty sweet.